# Counting the number of words without a specific substring using recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Suppose your alphabet is $\{A, C\}$. Every combination of letters is a word. How many words of length $N$ are there such that they do not have "ACA" as a substring?

It is required that the answer be in the form of a recurrence relation. My attempt so far is as follows:

Let $f_n$ be the number of words of length $n$ that satisfy the criteria above and $W_n$ any word of length $n$ satisfying the constraints. There are four cases:

**Case 1:** $\ $ $W_{n-1}$ ends in 'A' and $W_{n-2}$ ends in 'A'

Here, $W(n)$ can be either 'A' or 'C'. So $f_n = 2f_{n-1}$

**Case 2:** $\ $ $W_{n-1}$ ends in 'A' and $W_{n-2}$ ends in 'C'

Here, $W(n)$ can be either 'A' or 'C'. So $f_n = 2f_{n-1}$

**Case 3:** $\ $ $W_{n-1}$ ends in 'C' and $W_{n-2}$ ends in 'A'

We have $f_n = f_{n-1}$ (since $W(n)$ can only be 'C')

**Case 4:** $\ $ $W_{n-1}$ ends in 'C' and $W_{n-2}$ ends in 'C'

Yet again we have $W(n) = 2f_{n-1}$

I am not sure if the recurrence relation I drew is correct. I also don't know how to solve this piecewise recurrence relation to get a function of $N$. So, I am posting this as a question. Can someone validate my attempt and complete my solution?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: @lulu that is 101, this is ACA...

Comment: What's the difference?  Binary strings are binary strings...just replace $A$ with $1$ and $C$ with $0$.

Comment: No difference, just pointing out hehe

Comment: ya dude... it does. thanks a lot!!!